# Is there a way to Implement HTML5 video tags with BootStrap Modal and Custom AngularJS Attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

In an ASP environment, My problem is that IE11 opens Windows Media Player to play video files.

Using [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/36hd8b/ie_11_opens_up_media_player_to_play_videos/creuumv) I concluded that this was due to not having the appropriate `<video>...</video>` tags and `type=""` attribute.

However, the videos in question are using some custom AngularJS with Bootstrap as follows (simplified)

```
<div>
<h2>Title</h2>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="https://location/video.mp4" ><img src="@Url.Content("../directory/videoThumbnail.png")" /></a>
</div>
```

With an autoplay function:

```
function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
    var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
    trigger.click(function () {
        var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-theVideo"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
        $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('border', '0px');
        $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
            $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', '');
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    autoPlayYouTubeModal();
});
```

As you can see, this uses a modal and opens an iframe to play the video.

Is there a way to make IE11 happy with this current method, such as a way to implement the elements as suggested in the linked answer within the BootStrap modal? It currently seems as though using this method loses the ability to please IE11 by removing the [HTML5 `<video>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).